# Very basic .htaccess returning 500 Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

### What I'm expecting to happen

When someone visits `example.com/foo`, they see `example.com/index.php?page=foo`.

`example.com/index.php?page=foo` is working correctly.

### What actually happens

Instead, I see a **500 Internal Server Error** page, which states:

> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I have no access to the logs.

---

### Code

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
    switch($_GET["page"]){
        case "register" :
            echo "Registration Page Placeholder";
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this full message and full htaccess file?

Comment: I've added the rest of the message, however it didn't appear relevant. These are also the full `.htaccess` and `index.php` files.

Comment: Without access to the logs we can only speculate. It could be the `Options` line, because you're not allowed to set any options. It may be the Rewrite lines, because mod_rewrite isn't activated. It could be something in your PHP page which doesn't work....

Comment: @deceze Actually it's been solved below. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check whether the request is accessing `index.php` or not.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You're probably getting stuck with infinite rewrites.

Comment: Thank you for this - it worked perfectly. I'll accept as soon as I can.